# ::after selector affects another ::after selector - is this a bug?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, pseudo-element

This problem seems super strange. I'm using ::after selector to add the a golden line under the title, but it also affects an opacity gradient div (the yellow div), and adds a black line to the bottom of the div. Screenshot:
[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jn4yvuq/

My html and css:

```css
.audio-caption-background {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.audio-caption-background::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, yellow);
  border: none;
}

.page-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

.page-title::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-color: #CC9752;
  height: 3px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="page-title">TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="audio-caption-background">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The minute I remove the .page-title class the black border under the yellow div is gone. Also, if I remove the bootstrap classes it solves the problem too.
Why is that? I woudn't like the black border under the yellow div.

Comment: Your posted HTML and CSS doesn't seem to reproduce the problem you describe, or am I missing it?

Comment: include the bootstrap you are using, it's probably the culprit

Comment: I included jsfiddle link. What do you mean the bootstrap I'm using? It's version 4

Comment: still nothing on the jsfiddle (using chrome) ... which browser are you using?

Comment: I did not see any strange thing. You have an `:after` with width 100% that covers the `div` and it's back color is gradient.

Comment: Temani Afif: I just checked and actually on Firefox it seems fine, but on chrome I see the problem. You don't see the black border at the bottom of the yellow div on chrome?

I'm using Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: nothing on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the  `width` and `height` of `.audio-caption-background::after` to `calc(100% + 1px)` and adding `overflow: hidden` to `.audio-caption-background`.

You could alternatively delete the `.audio-caption-background::after` css and just put `background: linear-gradient(to right, black, yellow);` in `.audio-caption-background`.

Comment: @sir-haver Any time!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply add `border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;` to your title instead of using an `::after` to do the same job. You can eliminate the `::after` with a little fiddling on your `border-bottom`.

Comment: Thanks Desmond Mullen in my case I'm using a more transparent div, this was a simplified version just to understand the source of the problem